# CCLayerColor for Cocos2d v3

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

It seems CCLayerColor not found in Cocos2d 3.0

Here is my Cocos2d 2.0 code, I used CCLayerColor with 20% opacity.

```
ccColor4B color = {0,0,0,255};
CCLayerColor  *fadeLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:color];
[self addChild:fadeLayer z:5];
fadeLayer.opacity = 128;
```

In Cocos2d v3, I tried CCNodeColor, but its not semi opaque..always black.

```
CCNodeColor  *fadeLayer = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0]];
[self addChild: fadeLayer z:5];
fadeLayer.opacity = 128;
```

How can I achieve colour layer with semi transparency in Cocos2d v3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem Solved !

Solution is simple, now opacity range 0-1 not 1-255.

```
CCNodeColor  *fadeLayer = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0]];
[self addChild: fadeLayer z:5];
fadeLayer.opacity = 0.25f; // this fixed my problem.
```